# issues with async and await in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am launching the Location settings if it is disabled and trying to get the current location using the below code.

```
    if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enable the Location services", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
        }
        if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Ready)
        {
            Geoposition geoposition;
            Geocoordinate geocoordinate;
            GeoCoordinate geoCor = null;
            geoposition = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            geocoordinate = geoposition.Coordinate;
            geoCor = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(geocoordinate);
            ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery
            {
                GeoCoordinate = geoCor
            };
        }
```

once the "await" is executed, simply its moving to next statement. So not getting the proper result. I know await will work asynchronously but what about the next statements which are based one await result?

```
geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            geocoordinate = geoposition.Coordinate;
            geoCor = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(geocoordinate);
            ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery
            {
                GeoCoordinate = geoCor
            };
            reverseQuery.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error != null)
                        return;
                    if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Count > 0 && e.Result[0].Information != null && e.Result[0].Information.Address != null)
                        city = e.Result[0].Information.Address.City;
                };
            reverseQuery.QueryAsync();
            this.mapWithMyLocation.Center = geoCor;
            this.mapWithMyLocation.ZoomLevel = 10;
```

its showing geocoordinates correctly...but not getting the address.

Comment: There's nothing immediately visible as being wrong with that portion of code, and that is exactly how you are supposed to use that method.  What is the problem you are encountering and why do you think it is a problem?

Comment: @dodexahedron thanks for your reply... after await is fired nothing is happening... I added another scenario also in my question please see...thanks

Comment: Accept or still need help?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question right, then you should watch for location changed event or specify desired report interval. For example:

```
{
    ...
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    locator.MovementThreshold = 5d;
    // locator.ReportInterval = (uint)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds; 
    locator.PositionChanged += RaiseLocationChanged;
    ...
}

private void RaiseLocationChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Your reverse geocode etc. logic might go here...
    var location = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(args.Position.Coordinate);
}
```